# Need help referencing elements

Tags: javascript

I know I'm asking really simple questions but I'm a beginner and it the process of learning. I've got this code but I don know how to make it work. The output i expect is upon clicking the button it activates function insertAfter and adds text/paragraph that ill write.

I've tried: onclick='insertAfter(test,index.this)'
It didn't work and consoled said it was undefined.

```
var content = "";
Applications.forEach(generatetable);


function testfn(index, tdElement) {
        console.log(tdElement.parentElement);
        console.log(index);
        console.log(Applications[index].Name);


}
function generatetable(item, index, arrays) {

        var columns = "";

        columns = columns + "<td onclick='testfn(\"" + index + "\", this)'>" + "<button onclick='insertAfter(test?,???)' type=\"button\">Click Me!</button>" + item.UAID + "</td>";
        columns = columns + "<td>" + item.Name + "</td>";
        columns = columns + "<td>" + "<a href='www.wahtever.com'>map</a>" + "</td>";

        content = content + "<tr>" + columns + "</tr>";


}
var test = "<tr><td>fsdf</td></tr>";

document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = content;


function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

It is supposed to insert a paragraph preferably what i put in the test variable but if there is better is better solution please let me know.

Comment: You got undefined because asd and ofc are undefined... Anyway, you need to pass parameters: onclick="insertAfter(?, ?)"

Comment: I don't know what to put there i know the reference node is needed to be the one next to the button that is clicked and the new node is test. I've edited it so there is test where i've previously put it but what should the next one be?

Comment: Can you include some of the HTML at play here so we can see the code in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<button onclick='insertAfter(test,ElementID)>
The second refference node (ElementID) should be be the id of the element after which it is to be put. So it has to be somehow refferenced for example by id.